# Upon submit "Previous" button, display previous page along with webgrid as partical view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view called Education. In this view I have 2 submit buttons: one for "Add another Institution" and other for "Save & Next". When I click "Add another Institution", my code will display a webgrid which is partial view at the bottom of the Education view. When I click "Save & Next", it should take me to the next page Additional_info view.  Up to this point my code is doing exactly how I want.

In the Additional_info view I have again two submit buttons, one for "Previous" and other for "Save & Next".  When I click "Previous" it should take me to the previous page, which is "Education" view and display the webgrid based on the primary key that I am passing to each page.

My question is how to display my Education view along with webgrid when I click "Previous".  When I click previous button the control is going to [HttpGet]. But I have a code to display webgrid is in the [HttpPost]. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @chipChocolate please don't make edits like that anymore. It didn't really improve the readability. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster Amen to that!

Comment: @kavatap you should make Previous cause a POST to your Education action, so it'll go into the `[HttpPost]` action.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just return the Education action, or build the model and specify the Education view in the Post action.

```
public ActionResult Previous()
{
  //handle "Previous" post



  //handle the education view here
  var education = BuildEducationModel();
  return View("Education", education);


  //or just return the Education action.
  return Education();
}
```